# PHP mail not showing up on email

Tags: php, sendmail

I have created a small script that sends a multipart email via php the mail() (that has been a challenge in itself!).

When I test the script and send and email it all works fine, but when I try another address (one which has the same domain as the server) the email appears blank. All the content is there when you look at the raw code, but nothing displays.

Comment: what mailclient do you use to open the mails? have you tested other ones? whats shown if you send the mail to an gmx/msn/googlemail-account? what happens if you only send a "normal" text-mail without attachments?

Comment: Hi Oezi,I know its not the mail client and the emails come in fine when its a different server.

Comment: Check if your "multipart" code is correct. Some clients forgive syntactically wrong enclosing boundaries, some not.

Comment: Also check if you created an HTML mail but the client you use (if you use different ones) starts in text mode. If you offer no alternative text-only view one is sometimes tempted to think the email is "blank".

Comment: If you show the entire message (with headers and everything), what do you see? Perhaps post one of those, and maybe some code too?

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by removing the doctype tag from the code and left everything bare coded.

I also noticed the php variable

```
$body=' (html code here) '
```

The whitespace after `'` was causing the email to show up empty sometime... I'm not exactly sure why!

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered a similar issue and it was because I had a website www.example.com sending an email to me@example.com but the web server and email servers were on different machines. I had to ask the host to sort it so that the website wouldn't try to route emails within the server itself.

Comment: If you're using something like WHM, this would probably be the default case. If the server runs it's own DNS, it's likely set to receive emails @example.com using it's own mail server, even if you're using another mail service.

Comment: This is no question about routing but about the "appears blank" thing.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to sort this by changing my own code to instead using something a little more supported - [phpMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/).

I found this very easy to use and install into my own code. Also giving me as much flexibility as I had with my original code.

I guess though this isn't sorting the original problem, but it did seem to sort on my code.